# Regex for password must contain at least 8 characters, at least 1 number, letters and special characters

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression which should have at least one numeric character, both uper and lower case letters allowed, special characters also allowed I am using this expression

```
/^.*(?=.{6,10})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).*$
```

but it is not valid for max characters 10.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[\W_]).{6,10}$
```

The above regex would allow 6 to 10 characters only. And it also checks for at-least one digit, upper or lowercase letter and at-least one special character (characters other than letters and numbers).

Comment: why not: `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*?[a-zA-Z])(?=.*?[\W_]).{6,10}$`

Comment: `(?=.*?[\W_])` is redundant in this case.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Smaller is better and don't forget one less lookahead :)

Comment: i don't know op wants to check for atleast a special character or not. If he don't want then he must go with yours.

Answer (score 2):

The following regular expression will limit your length and allow special characters.

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,10}$
```

Comment: Same comment as what I posted on Avinash's answer, there is no need for `(?=.{6,10}$)` lookahead as that can be done on match itself in place of `.*`

Comment: I have upvoted both of you believing both are correct answers :)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?=.{8,})(?=.+\d)(?=.+[A-Za-z])(?=.+\W).*$
```

- 8 char min
- 1 numeric min
- 1 letter min
- 1 special char min

Comment: I think the core (the order-independence) needs more explanation. Otherewise you are quite close to [answer], thanks. Consider taking the highly recommded [tour].

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't do salutations in the first place, and salutations quite that friendly are highly troublesome. Please refrain from adding those.